# SyncReplicasOptimizer does not synchronize workers?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use SyncReplicasOptimizer to train a model by a synchronized SGD. I followed the example in mnist_replicas.py. I am using 1 ps and 2 workers.

I added a variable `epoch` and an operation to increase it by 1 (This is just to understand what is going on):

```py
 epoch = tf.Variable(0, name="epoch", trainable=False)
 inc_epoch_op = tf.assign_add(epoch, 1)
```

then after creating the session by the chief I do the following in my training loop :

```py
while True:
    train_feed =  # my train feed
    _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
    loss = sess.run(total_loss, feed_dict = train_feed)
    if is_chief:
        sess.run(inc_epoch_op)
    print '## epoch ', epoch.eval(sess)
    if epoch.eval(sess) > 4:
        break
```

My understanding of SyncReplicasOptimizer as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard3/tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer.md) is that at every execution of my training loop, it will wait for my 2 workers to end their backpropagation, average the gradients and apply them.

So I am expecting that both workers print :

```py
## epoch  1
## epoch  2
## epoch  3
## epoch  4
## epoch  5
```

Which is the case for my chief worker, but the other one prints :

```py
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  2
## epoch  3
## epoch  3
## epoch  4
## epoch  5
```

and that patterns changes between executions.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Moreover, It happens that the chief worker ends, whereas the other worker does not get further after printing :

```py
## epoch 4
```

and keeps looping. It seems to be a race condition where the chief worker ends, and the variable `epoch` is somehow corrupted, so the other worker never sees it incremented to `5` and then never stops.
Any idea to avoid that?

Thanks for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762872/distributed-tensorflow-tf-train-syncreplicasoptimizer-seems-not-synchronized I saw a relevant question and found the `SyncReplicasOptimizer ` doesn't works like you think. I'm not sure this is a bug or a desired feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you are observing, and I think we can unpack them to understand things better.

Sync replicas works by adding barriers to the training process. One of the barriers prevents the worker from finishing its step until the chief worker has updated the weights from the previous iteration. If the chief worker exits, then, it might be that the other workers are never unblocked, hence you seeing the non-chief worker stuck at epoch 4 (it is actually stuck trying to run the train_op, I think).

Also, what session are you using? If you're using a MonitoredTrainingSession with the correct hook, it was not designed to allow you to call session.run more than once per iteration in the training loop, so this might be creating the nondeterminism you're seeing in what gets printed in the normal workers. To see the right behavior I'd do something like

```
if is_chief:
  inc_epoch_op = tf.assign_add(epoch, 1)
else:
  inc_epoch_op = epoch

_, __, ep = sess.run([train_op, global_step, inc_epoch_op])
print "epoch:", ep
```

Is this still weird?